# Running example code of wxpython but Menu Item does not show up

Tags: macos, wxpython

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200,100))
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.CreateStatusBar() # A Statusbar in the bottom of the window

        # Setting up the menu.
        filemenu= wx.Menu()

        # wx.ID_ABOUT and wx.ID_EXIT are standard IDs provided by wxWidgets.
        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About"," Information about this program")
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()
        filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,"E&xit"," Terminate the program")

        # Creating the menubar.
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu,"&File") # Adding the "filemenu" to the MenuBar
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)  # Adding the MenuBar to the Frame content.
        self.Show(True)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "Sample editor")
app.MainLoop()
```

I can see the &File menu but it is empty. It doesn't contain the about and exit items. What am I missing here?

Here's the original wiki page with the code: [wxPython wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started#Adding_a_menu_bar)

Thanks a lot.

Also: if I substitute the ID_ABOUT and ID_EXIT with some random numbers it works. Anyways I wouldn't like to do it like this, since it isn't the standard way.

Comment: Works fine with me on python2.7..(Debian Jessie Linux).........ID_ABOUT and ID_EXIT used....hmmm..

Comment: I think that the problem is strictly related to MacOSX.. Python2.7.10 here

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023255/wxpython-menu-bar-not-displaying) answered mine. It creates the menu items there, but I didn't notice because I didn't double check. Thanks to anyone who was interested somehow to this question

Comment: check this link here too..it seems like stock ids was applicable app menu widget on OSX only....http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/12092..not really a bug but OS  platform issue